# Android font size not scaling on tablet

Tags: android, fonts, size, tablet

In Android, I'm using DP for everything, and SP for fonts.
In my game menu, all the graphics scale correctly over multiple screens and screen densities, except for the fonts that are using SP.

I searched around and all I can find is definitions for DP versus SP, but nobody is actually giving the proper reason why the graphics are scaling correctly, but the font size is not scaling.
I also tried changing the font size to use DP instead of SP, but they are still tiny on 160dpi, or on the Xoom tablet.

How can I make it so the font size scales proportional to everything else that's already using DP?

Comment: Some sample layouts and screenshots might help us understand the nature of your problem.